# Web App Authorization Loader hangs up on Google Sites after Upgrading Authorization System

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

Whenever a user authorizes the embedded App with the new Authorization System, it hangs and doesn't show the UI

It stays this

> (loader) Waiting for authorization...

Nevertheless, the Web App appears after refreshing the Page

This is an annoying issue that I've had for a few months and was wondering if any of you guys have the same issue?

Answer (score 3):

This has been logged in the Issue Tracker as a bug here - https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3049

Please track the conversation there.

Comment: Thanks Arun, didn't find it posted on stackoverflow so I gave it try